# (Android) How to convert a time raw string (with timezone) to another string format with the same timezone

Tags: java, android, date, time, timezone

I have a time raw string, "2016-05-15T12:42:00.000-04:00" and I want to convert the string to "Wed 15 May 2016 12:42", which keeps the same timezone (-04:00) as its original source.

I have tried **SimpleDateFormat** but using it returns different timezones that are not the same as the timezone in my original string. Please help me achieve this in Android Studio!

Other examples:

2016-05-15T15:42:00.000-08:00 -> Wed 15 May 2016 15:42

2016-05-15T14:44:00.000-01:00 -> Wed 15 May 2016 14:44

```
public static String formatDateString(String originDateString) {
    //Original format 2016-05-15T12:42:00.000-04:00
    SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    SimpleDateFormat resultFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
    String dateString = "";
    try {
        Date date = originalFormat.parse(originDateString);
        dateString = resultFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //returned format: Tue 14 May 2016 12:42
    return dateString;
}
```

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Comment: No Effort Shown - StackOverflow is not a "code writing" service , Mr.Vu

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask a good question

Comment: Sorry, I just post my first question. I'll add what I've tried

Comment: @TilakMadichetti: just added my attempt sir!

Comment: Thanks for coming back and improving your original post, keep it up!

Comment: newbie here sir! Just got my answer and feel excited!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try saving it first without the TZ information

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```